# Regular expression to match valid IP addresses over multiple lines

Tags: regex

How can I construct a regular expression that matches a valid IP address [1-255] and is able to be multiline and allow whitespace? The values will be typed out and submitted like this:

```
10.10.10.10
100.100.100.100
192.1.1.1.1
192.158.1.38
```

and so on with no limit.

I have this expression that I have tweaked but only does a fraction of what I need it to do:

```
"^(?:(?:2(?:[0-4][0-9]|5[0-5])|[0-1]?[0-9]?[0-9])\.){3}(?:(?:2([0-4][0-9]|5[0-5])|[0-1]?[0-9]?[0-9])\/?[0-4]?[0-9]?\s?\r?\n?\.?\d)*$\b"
```

Answer (score 0):

Something as simple as the following should do it:

```
\b(?<!\.)(?:(?:\d{1,2}|1\d{2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.){3}(?:\d{1,2}|1\d{2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])(?!\.)\b
```

Not too sure what you think you're doing with all the new line checks though, regex engines handle new lines on their own just fine. [See it in action here](https://regex101.com/r/DV5mYS/1).

Comment: Hey thanks for the help, but this doesn't do exactly what I need. The values are going to be inputted into a text area, so a user might list them on different like so. With spaces and line breaks in between each IP. So, the expression still needs to be able to handle and match that white space.

Comment: Spaces don't matter, it's a regular expression. Show what you believe doesn't match but should, I gave you a link to the playground.